# Decorate Service in Directive based on Attributes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Disclosure: I'm new to angular, so if I'm doing something that appears strange or just plain wrong, feel free to point that out.

I have a directive `vpMap` that I want to use like this:

```
<div my-map with-tile-layers with-geolocator></div>
```

I have a `Map` service that I want to decorate conditionally, based on the attributes of the directive that begin with `with`

It looks something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.map',[])
   .service('Map',someServiceFunction)
   .directive('myMap',['Map','$provide',function(Map,$provide) {

      return {
        controller: function($scope,$element,$attrs) {

          angular.forEach($attrs,function(val,key) {
             if(key.match(/^with/)) {
               switch(key) {
                 case 'withTileLayers':
                 $provide.decorator(Map,someDecoratorFunction);
                 break;
               }
             }
          });

        }
      };

   }]);
```

It's at this point that I discover I can't access the $provide service in my directive, although I'm not sure why. According to the documentation you can inject anything into directives and, I thought $provide was one of those global angular services like $http

Is this bad architecture? What rules am I not understanding?

Comment: Is there an error thrown?

Comment: Oops, sorry yes - http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$provideProvider%20%3C-%20$provide%20%3C-%20myMapDirective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providers are meant to be used by the `$injector` in the configuration phase.

From the [providers guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe):

> Once the configuration phase is over, **interaction with providers is
>   disallowed** and the process of creating services starts. We call this
>   part of the application life-cycle the run phase.

So you would have to use the config block for decorating.

### Attempted Fix

To decorate a service *conditionally*, you may use some predicate inside the decorator's function, something along the lines of this (not tested):

```js
// define a predicate that checks if an object starts with a key 
function keyInObject(obj, key) {
    var propKeys = Object.keys(obj),
        index = propKeys && propKeys.length || 0;
    while (index--) {
        if (propKeys[index].indexOf(key) === 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

app.config(function($provide) {

    // uhmm, decorate
    $provide.decorator('Map', function($delegate) {
        var service = $delegate;

        // only extend the service if the predicate fulfills        
        keyInObject(service, 'with') && angular.extend(service, {
            // whatever, man
        });

        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

However, *even this won't help us*, as we need to get the keys in the *linking phase*, which is well after the service have been injected (and decorated).

To make sure you fully understand the meaning of decoration here; we use decoration to permanently alter the object (the service) structure. *Decoration refers to the object's meta data, not its state*.

### Solution

Given the above, the best choice would be to simply create a service with all the required functionality, and abandon decoration altogether. Later, while inside `link` you can use the iteration to decide which of the methods to call, e.g.:

```js
// I took the liberty of switching the positions of key/val arguments
// for semantics sake...
angular.forEach($attrs, function(key, val) {
    if (val.match(/^with/)) {
        switch (val) {
            case 'withTileLayers':
                Map.useTileLayers(); // use specific API in the service
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Eliran! I realized after I should be using a factory to provide me with a factory method that returns an object that I can then decorate by simply using an extend on that individual object.

Comment: @Adam, what do you mean? did you go with a different solution? can you post a demo to illustrate it? i'd love to see it in action.