# how to call different function on different button click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two buttons .I want to call a decorator function on button click ..and on another button I want to call service main method ..

how it is possible .
I want if user click on first button it show

```
 console.log('--- this os')
```

I want if user click on second button it show

```
 console.log('this is name');
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JPTtScno7Saru1GwwkUn?p=preview

// Code goes here

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('cntrl',function(newservice,$scope){



  $scope.callDecorator=function(){
    newservice.getName();
  }

  $scope.withoutDecorator=function(){
    newservice.getName();
  }
}).service('newservice',function(){

    this.getName=function(){
      console.log('this is name');
    }

}).decorator('newservice',function($delegate){
  $delegate.getName=function(){
    console.log('--- this os')
  }


  return $delegate
})
```

Comment: Not sure you can do that as all instances are affected. But if you add an extra property, you can achieve it, calling with differnet parameters. Not sure it is sufficient for you

Comment: To decorate a service conditionally, you may use some predicate inside the decorator's function,  Refer  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326755/decorate-service-in-directive-based-on-attributes-in-angularjs